# Just can't seem to finish particular file downloads. Utorrent, Skype, etc. No firewall, no AV

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, timeout

**Problem:** I've been trying to download files from the Internet and some of them are getting stuck in a certain percentage (e.g. uTorrent.exe stops at 83%). I don't have a firewall, I'm pretty sure Windows' firewall is deactivated.

**My computer:** Windows 7, wireless Internet adapter.
Other settings where downloads work: Same computer, different OS (Linux), different computer (laptop) wired download.

**What have I tried:** Downloading with Opera, with Firefox, using download managers (jDownloader, Getright) asking someone to upload the files to mediafire. Nothing has worked for me.

It's not ALL .exe files, just some of them. For instance, I can download the installer for google Earth, but if I try downloading the offline Installer it will get stocked. Downloading podcasts from iTunes is not working, I suppose because most of them are just mp3 files downloaded from the Internet.

This behavior is very weird, I just disconnected my USB adapter and tried with the 3G internet from my phone and I was able to download the files. Then I disconnected the 3G, reconnected the usb device, and I was able to download the files and podcasts for two or three minutes. Then it went back to the old behavior of timing out the connections.

Do you think this is a problem with the wireless adapter, or the drivers?

Comment: Have you used up your Internet bandwidth for the month?

Comment: Please can you run a ```ping <router ip> -t``` when trying to download to see if your wireless connection fails entirely during a download, or just the download itself.  Also, is the issue dependent on the size of the file?

Comment: **Hand-E-Food** I don't have a limit, the 3G I was referring to is not the connection giving the problems, it's the other connection (ADSL)
**Paul** I can ping the router ok, in fact I can browse websites without any problem. utorrent.exe is 627KB, Skype is about 1.1MB, google earth is 16.3MB, the podcasts I get are usually 20-30 MB